# UITableView: How to make the UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton appear on selection?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'd like to have all the rows on my table view use UITableViewCellAccessoryNone (e.g. no button on the right) unless they are selected, at which point I want to use UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton.  E.g. only one row (or none if there's no selection) has the button at a time.

Is this possible?  Doing the usual thing of implementing accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath doesn't seem to work dynamically - e.g. it only gets called once regardless of what's selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the contents of a cell, you'll want to call -reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: on your tableview.

Answer (score 3):

Note for others trying this.. the accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath delegate method is now depreciated, you'll get this message if you try it:

> WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due
>   to delegate implementation of
>   tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:
>   in .  Please
>   remove your implementation of this
>   method and set the cell properties
>   accessoryType and/or
>   editingAccessoryType to move to the
>   new cell layout behavior.  This method
>   will no longer be called in a future
>   release.

Instead, implement the setSelected method in your UITableViewCell subclass.. e.g.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state

if (selected) {
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
} else {
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

..then use the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation method as described above.